# Insert Variable inside Echo

Tags: php, html, variables

I'm trying to use a PHP variable to add a href value for a link in an echo statement. How can I insert `$myimage after a href="billing/"`, the problem is it doesn't show anything. Here's the code.

```
$myimage = $row['image'];

echo '<td><div align="right"><a href="billing/'.$myimage.'"></a></div></td>';
```

Comment: Whats the output of `var_dump($myimage);`

Comment: string(40) "Screen Shot 2015-10-07 at 1.21.46 PM.png"

Comment: Then there is nothing wrong with that code. Can you also tell us what is the output of that echo when you view source?

Comment: Could it be something to do with the spaces in the string?

Comment: The output of the echo is the filename of the image.

Comment: What happens when you click on the link? What is the url that it takes you to?

Comment: I want to show the image path when i click the link.

Comment: Do you mean like this: `echo '<td><div align="right"><a href="billing/'.$myimage.'">'.$myimage.'</a></div></td>';` so that the name of the image is the link?

Comment: OMG that works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't add anything as the text for the link. You can fix it like this:

```
echo '<td><div align="right"><a href="billing/'.$myimage.'">' . $myimage . '</a></div></td>';
```

That should make it so the name of the image is the link.